# Unattributed Reproduction of S.E. Content

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing

I know that S.E. places a [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license on material and I just ran across this:

http://www.codeitive.com/0zxVjUekqU/how-to-remove-the-warning-in-gcc-46-missing-initializer-wmissingfieldinitializers.html

Which is pretty clearly [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373695/how-to-remove-the-warning-in-gcc-4-6-missing-initializer-wmissing-field-initi) edited down a bit, including the removal of names.

There is no indication of the source, or that it is not original material.   Interestingly, at the bottom of the page there's a note:

> © 2014 codeitive.com, All rights reserved   user contributions **licensed under cc by-sa 3.0** with attribution required.

That site obviously contains *a lot* of other ripped Stack Overflow material. It seems to me this is a violation of the licence; I am irritated that the stuff I and others work hard on in an explicit CC-SA context is being presented as original material on a site with advertising (i.e., someone else is using it to make money without appropriate attribution).

Am I wrong about the legal issue here?

Comment: Email the team using the contact us link.

Comment: Okay -- I've sent the message.

Comment: @Tim: Nothing much has been done for all the past cases... I've already come across quite a few now. I propose that StackExchange requires logging in to view content, so that scrapers can be tracked and banned.

Comment: @user21820 well that would lose 90% of their traffic so that's not going to happen. Do you have some past cases where they're not attributing? Remember that SE allows scraping, as lost as they attribute.

Comment: @Tim: I posted http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257082/260881 which as you can see attracted lots of unsubstantiated disagreement. What do you think? The two mentioned there are not attributing as required.

Comment: @goldilocks: I think don't bother about it anymore. From the response to my question I gather that no one here really cares, and I feel exactly the way you do. =(

Comment: @user21820 I'm not for punishing the innocent for the crimes of the guilty by trying to prevent scraping or restricting whatever public data dump mechanisms exist.  S.E. has the resources to threaten legal action, though, and I'd like to hope they do sometimes.  As to whether that is worth pursing if someone ignores the threat is another question,  I guess.

Comment: @goldilocks: Ah that is precisely the problem. I don't think they do, and I don't expect them to with the current system because it's a losing battle. But how exactly do you think my suggestion punishes the innocent? Still nobody has given a satisfactory answer to that. One says "I'm rich and can afford to use SE almost the whole day" and yet he admits he usually doesn't reach the limit of 1Gb that I suggested. Another says we just have to wait a long time for the SE people to deal with each issue, but that's not going to work. The rest just react as if people will get hurt, but will any?

Comment: But if someone wants to keep a mirror updated hourly, that's fine if they obey the CC-SA terms.   How you could prevent stuff like codeitive.com without also preventing that **theoretical, legitimate** user?  If people are breaking the law, they should be dealt with appropriately.  Beyond that, they should be free to do whatever they want.   I just don't think you could come up with pragmatic limits that would really prevent this effectively without getting *really* restrictive.  If I can't rip > 1 GB a day, that doesn't stop me from violating the CC-SA on the 1 GB that I do rip. Etc.

Comment: @goldilocks: Then I'm afraid you'll have to live with law-breakers because you'll see that nobody will succeed in dealing with them appropriately (if they even bother to at all). Why don't you wait and see if the SCRAPERS you are aware of get dealt with? If they do, then I fully agree with you.